# MySQL Entity Framework Tables are not created

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, signalr

Following this guide: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider
I have attempted to setup a connection to my MySQL database with the Entity Framework.
The connection goes through successfully, but whenever I run my code I get the following error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'helpcontext.users' doesn't exist

My Context class looks like this:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class HelpContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionComment> QuestionComments { get; set; }

    public HelpContext() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }
}
```

My "MySQLInitializer" class looks like this:

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<HelpContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(HelpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            // if database did not exist before - create it
            context.Database.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
            var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
              "helpcontext"));

            // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Schema is created on the mysql instance fine, but no tables what so ever are created, causing the application to crash with the afforementioned error.
Any idea what I have done wrong?

EDIT:
Turns out the issue came from an earlier attempt at following other solution for my original issue with the tables not being created.
I had this piece of code in my context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Channel>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChatMessage>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionComment>().MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
```

Turns out that's bad. Removing the method from my class fixed the issue.

Comment: helpcontext is a schema? MySQL ignores schema creation. Maybe this is your problem. Try to remove schema definition from your entities/mappings.

Comment: Ehm what?  
like 'string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
              "somethingElse"));' instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had another issue in my code. See the EDIT for more information.